# How to access JavaScript prototype methods in Angular 2+ view?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-template

Is there a way to access JavaScript global object constructors, like Array in the angular 5 view without declaring them in the component?

For my scenario, i need access to Array.from() in the view.

I am currently declaring Array:any as part of the fields of my components, and initializing it in the constructor as: this.Array = Array. 
Is there a better/recommended way?

Comment: Why are you doing `Array.from()` in a _template_? (That seems like [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) to me, that sort of logic doesn't belong there.) If it's something like `*ngFor="Array.from(data)"` you should instead transform that data into an iterable in your Component, likely in the oncomplete handler of your service call, and give that to your template. That's the whole point of [separating concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and having a template that is distinct from the controller.

Comment: Recommend using a custom pipe or use classes to do the conversion before assigning. But I have tried global object prototype functions and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with a hack, `{{ [].constructor.from(foo) }}`.

This should never be done in real application because it has code smell (as the comment mentions), affects the performance in negative way and indicates potential XY problem.

This kind of logic should be moved to component class. Even if `Array.from` should be used in template to create arrays from other iterables, it preferably has to be used as *pure* pipe:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'array' })
class ArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(iterable: ArrayLike<any> | Iterable<any>): Array<any> {
    return Array.from(iterable);
  }
}
```